# Kibana is stuck on "completing setup" when first starting up

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, containers, kibana, elk

I am trying to build a local elasticsearch instance using Docker. I have started Elasticsearch container and then started Kibana container. I have gone through the process of connecting kibana container to elasticsearch container and verifying the kibana instance. It goes into the start up sequence in the kibana front end. Everything finishes except the last step which is "Completing Setup". I have waited for over an hour, if not multiple hours, and it is still loading.

I have tried restarting / deleting and recreating the kibana container, and im just met with the same issue.
Also when I close the browser while it was loading and reconnect to the kibana front end, im just met with "kibana server is not ready yet."

Im not sure what the issue is. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Tried deleting and rebuilding kibana container. Got same result.
Tried restarting and got same result.
I tried looking at the kibana container logs and I wasn't able to find anything helpful, at least not that I personally could interpret.

Comment: Have you tried simply refreshing the page?

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar issue! I stopped the Kibana and started again and it worked for me! I don't know how!

Comment: Same in my case. The process hung for more than 90 minutes. Stopped Kibana in the terminal, restarted, went to the browser, refreshed the page and surprisingly everything ran as expected. This is a bug in Kibana that should be resolved: first there should be some feedback while running and second there should be some information about the cause of the problem.